# react native 0.68.2 after react-native run-android Error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'configurations')

Tags: android, react-native, npm-install

**TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'configurations')**

> facing this issue when running the project with react-native
> run-android

```
 at Object.dependencyConfig (/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/build/config/index.js:102:37)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-config/build/loadConfig.js:47:61
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at getDependencyConfig (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-config/build/loadConfig.js:44:51)
    at Object.get @ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider [as @ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-config/build/loadConfig.js:99:18)
    at warnAboutManuallyLinkedLibs (/Users/CBL-MAC/Documents/Project/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/link/warnAboutManuallyLinkedLibs.js:39:43)
    at displayWarnings (/Users/CBL-MAC/Documents/Project/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js:82:44)
    at Object.runAndroid [as func] (/Users/CBL-MAC/Documents/Project/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js:97:3)
    at Command.handleAction (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:192:23)
    at Command.listener (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/commander/index.js:315:8)
```

Answer (score 5):

**react native 0.68.2,if this error comes to you**

> you should change the file under
>
> node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/build/config/index.js

```
function dependencyConfig(folder, userConfig) {
  comment this line
  // const configurations = userConfig.configurations || [];
     
  // redeclare again
 var configurations="";
```

Comment: Worked for me - thanks! (I'm using RN 0.69.4)

Answer (score 3):

we just needs to upgrade @react-native-community/cli

```
npm i -g @react-native-community/cli@7.0.4
```

Comment: Hi, Tried installing it still the same issue.

Did it worked for you ?

Comment: 7.0.4 only worked not the latest version. i have tried 8.0.6 and 9.3.0. hope it helps someone

Comment: Hi, the 7.0.4 worked for me, check if you have another version installed locally.